# Mapping NGINX to the same port

Tags: asp.net, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created the default ASP NET Core Web Api application with docker support and trying to publish it with docker-compose, but haven't luck;
I think it fails because Nginx getting stuck somewhere between listening to 80 port and proxying to the same 80 port.
But is it somehow possible to do that?

My docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: ./WebApplication2    
    expose:
      - "80"
  nginx:
    image: "nginx"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx/
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

My dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication2.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication2.dll"]
```

My NGINX config

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:80/;
        }
    }
}
```

Error form logs

```
2021/08/12 23:04:16 [alert] 25#25: 1024 worker_connections are not enough
2021/08/12 23:04:16 [error] 25#25: *1021 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /weatherforecast HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/weatherforecast", host: "localhost"
```

Comment: When you `proxy_pass http://localhost:80`, you're having the Nginx container call itself.  Do you mean for it to call the other container?  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the host names that are available in this context.

Comment: @DavidMaze So it is not possible to make my app and nginx listen to the same port in terms of one network, isn't it ?
I read about networking, but it is more about isolating services, but, I think, nginx have to be connected to my service.

Comment: Both containers can listen to the same port, but each separately thinks it is `localhost`.

Comment: @DavidMaze got it, thanks a lot for a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidMaze comments.

> When you proxy_pass http://localhost:80, you're having the Nginx container call itself.
>
> Both containers can listen to the same port, but each separately thinks it is localhost.